# phpstorm - загадка undefined variable

Tags: php, phpstorm

Такая ситуация:
есть два файла - в одном обьявлено два массива

```
$arrGlobalTableCode = array(
'orders' => 1,
'order_executors' => 2,
);

$arrGlobalTableCode2 = array(
'orders' => 1,
'order_executors' => 2,
);
```

во втором файле подключаю первый

require_once 'lib/table_type.php';

использую массивы:

```
error_log("arr1 = ".print_r($arrGlobalTableCode,1)); 

error_log("arr2 = ".print_r($arrGlobalTableCode2,1));
```

первым массив выводится нормально, второй подсвечен ворнингом undefined variable и соот. ничего не выводится

в чем тут дело может быть?
если скопировать массив2 из первого файла и напрямую вставить в код второго файла - все определяется и выводится

Comment: У тебя require идет в начале файла?)

Comment: а какая разница? один массив из файла доступен

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка области видимости, попробуй во втором файле объявить переменные глобальными. Вот документация: [Область видимости переменной](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)

```
global $arrGlobalTableCode, $arrGlobalTableCode2;

error_log("arr1 = ".print_r($arrGlobalTableCode,1)); 
error_log("arr2 = ".print_r($arrGlobalTableCode2,1));
```

Comment: global помогает, конечно, но непонятно почему первым массив виден, а второй нет. возможно надо как-то почистить настройки проекта,кэш, память и прочее. скажем, в xcode для этого есть отдельная процедура, а в phpstorm не знаю таких вещей

Comment: @Rapax Все нормально, так и должно быть, если верить документации, почитай на досуге: [Область видимости](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)